# How to check for number range and if a string value in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a case where an entity gives a directory size in case it is present, otherwise it gives  a string saying "IATEMPDIR does not exist".

Is there any way to identify whether the entity `client.tempsize` lt `65594` && `client.tempsize` value is not a string (so when it has `IATEMPDIR does not exist` value it should also return this query). In this case how do I check both **number range** as well as **if a string**?

i am using percolate

```
PUT /eg/.percolator/1
{   
    "sort": {
        "rule.step": { "order": "asc" }
    },
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "query": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                          "match": {
                             "client.name": "Athena"
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          "range": {
                             "client.tempsize": {
                                    "lt": 65594
                             }
                          }
                      }
                    ]                   
               }               
           }
        }
    },
    "rule": {
        "ruledesc": "Client should be Athena & tempsize should have sufficient space (eg: > 65594) and should not be a string",
        "step": 1
    }    
}
```

my doc

```
GET /eg/message/_percolate
{
    "doc": {
        "client": {
            "name": "Athena",
            "tempsize": "IATEMPDIR does not exist"
        }
    }
}
```

Above doc gives me `...MapperParsingException[failed to parse [client.tempsize]]; nested: NumberFormatException...`, but when I use `"tempsize": 12` it gives back proper result.

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "total": 1,
   "matches": [
      {
         "_index": "eg",
         "_id": "1"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Update**

After going through **ppearcy**'s answer. I changed the mapping to

```
PUT /eg/message/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "client": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "tempsize": {
               "type": "long",
               "ignore_malformed" : "true"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and the below doc does not result in my query, and is ignoring string

```
GET /eg/message/_percolate
{
    "doc": {
        "client": {
            "name": "Athena",
            "tempsize": "IATEMPDIR does not exist"
        }
    }
}
```

So if I give `"tempsize": "65594"`, does that consider numbers inside double quotes (as giving numbers less than 65594 gives back my query) ? Or will it break somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the "ignore_malformed" : "true" on your mapping for the field.

This will allow you to still index documents and non-numbers will just be ignored and can be queried with missing/exist query types.

Using lucene query syntax to simplify, your end query would look like:

```
_missing_:client.tempsize OR client.tempsize:[0 TO 65594]
```

Check out the number section here for more info:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Comment: Does that mean, it ignores string value and treats everything as integer? Even "65594" is a integer?

Comment: Yeah, but it depends on your field mapping. If you are not setting a mapping, elasticsearch guesses based on the first data it sees. This guessed behavior is OK for hacking, but should be setting explicit mappings for most use cases.